# Get all funds which has at least minimum data points

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, subquery

I have two tables

1) Fund details

```
ID    Symbol
-------------------
1     ABC
2     XYZ
```

2) Fund Price data

```
Fund_id    date                       Price
-------------------------------------------
1          2014-07-01 00:00:00.000    25.25
1          2014-07-02 00:00:00.000    25.45
......
2          2014-07-01 00:00:00.000    75.25
2          2014-07-02 00:00:00.000    75.42
.......
```

Now what I want to achieve is:

Here I am fetching the monthly data of a particular Fund as below:

```
SELECT YEAR(date) [Year], MONTH(date) [Month], 
DATENAME(MONTH,date) [Month Name], COUNT(1) [Sales Count], F.Symbol 
FROM FundData FD inner join FundDetails F on F.ID = FD.Fund_ID 
where F.Symbol = 'ABC' 
GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date), DATENAME(MONTH, date), F.Symbol
```

Output:

```
Year    Month Month Name    Sales Count Symbol
-------------------------------------------
2014    4     April         21          ABC
2014    5     May           21          ABC
2014    6     June          21          ABC
2014    7     July          3           ABC
.......

Total Rows: 301
```

So here this is only for only particular fund which has returned `301` rows.

Now I want to get all the funds from the Fund details table which has rows less than given count `ex 216` which I will pass as a parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it:

```
Declare @YourParameter int = 110

WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT YEAR(date) [Year], MONTH(date) [Month], 
    DATENAME(MONTH,date) [Month Name], COUNT(1) [Sales Count], F.Symbol 
    FROM FundData FD inner join FundDetails F on F.ID = FD.Fund_ID 
    where F.ID 
    IN (SELECT z.ID FROM FundDetails z)
    GROUP BY F.Symbol, YEAR(date), MONTH(date), DATENAME(MONTH, date)
)
SELECT Symbol, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM CTE
GROUP BY Symbol
having COUNT(*) >= @YourParameter
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Following query:

```
Declare @YourParameter int = 10

SELECT  YEAR(date) [Year], 
        MONTH(date) [Month], 
        DATENAME(MONTH,date) [Month Name], 
        COUNT(1) [Sales Count], 
        F.Symbol 
FROM FundData FD 
INNER JOIN FundDetails F on FD.ID = F.Fund_ID
Where FD.ID IN (SELECT z.Fund_ID
                 FROM FundDetails z
                 WHERE z.Fund_ID=FD.ID
                 GROUP BY z.Fund_ID, YEAR(z.date), MONTH(z.date)
                 HAVING COUNT(*) <= @YourParameter
                 )
GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date), DATENAME(MONTH, date), F.Symbol
```

Comment: No this is not what I want.. Here you are passing `ABC` which is for single fund. I want all funds whose month count has less than `YourParameter`.

Comment: It's not working. You are interchanging the fields with both the tables and now it's taking more than 2 min and still running